# Passing a Entity over a network?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have been studying Java networking for a while.
I am using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream for the I/O between sockets.

Is this possible to transfer a Entity or Model from server to client and vise versa?
How can I implement this? Am I suppose to implement the Entity or Model to Serializable?

Your response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... why sending an object through I/O stream? What's wrong with XML?

However, you can always send/receive an object through I/O stream as long as the sender can serialize the object and the receiver can deserialize the object. Hope it helps

Comment: XML has a large overhead. RMI or Hessian provide much better performance, with Hessian you can also easily switch to XML on demand (Burlap).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what sort of special thing you mean to denote by capital-E Entity and capital-M Model; these terms don't have any fixed, privileged meaning in Java (although they might with respect to a certain API or framework.) In general, if by these you just mean some specific Java objects, then yes, you can send any sort of objects this way, and yes, they would be required to implement Serializable. The only limitations would be if these objects contained members whose values wouldn't make sense on the other end of the pipe -- like file paths, etc.

Note that if you send one object, you'll end up sending every other object it holds a non-transient reference to, as well.

Comment: I apologize for the capitalization. I'll see try this.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to look at one of these two libraries

Google gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Converts Java object to JSON and back. advantage is that the object can be consumed or generated by Javascript. I have also used this for Java-Java RPC, but it gives you flexibility if you want to target browsers later

Google protocol buffers: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/
This is what google uses for RPC. Implementations for Java, C, Python. If you need performance and the smallest size, this is the one to go with (The trade off is you can't look at the data easily to debug problems, like you can with gson, which generates plaint text JSON).